How to use a junction table in Room to get data in a specific format
I’m working with Room database in Android and have three data classes representing my tables:
data class Train(id: Int, isFollow: Boolean)
data class TrainStatus(id: Int, trainId: Int, origin: String, destination: String)
data class PreviousTrain(id: Int, trainStatusId: Int, previousTrainStatusId: Int)

In TrainStatus, trainId is a foreign key that references id from the Train class.
PreviousTrain is a junction table where trainStatusId and previousTrainStatusId are foreign keys referencing id from TrainStatus.
I want to query the database and get a response in the following format:
data class Response(
    val train: Train,
    val trainStatusWithPreviousTrain: List<TrainStatusWithPreviousTrain>
)

data class TrainStatusWithPreviousTrain(
    val trainStatus: TrainStatus, 
    val previousTrain: TrainStatus
)

How can I use the junction table to create a Room query that will give me the data in the Response format?

In short you have a POJO with @Embedded for the parent and with @Relation for the child/children using the associateBy parameter with a Junction to specify the table and respective columns of the junction.

@Embedded will build the embedded object (if the relevant columns exist)
@Relation without the associateBy parameter (assuming the correct parent and children columns) will extract ALL of the related children into a list of objects or a single object (first according to the order of the output)
@Relation with the associateBy parameter with correctly coded specified parameters, will utilise the junction (associative/mapping/reference and other terms) table to extract the  related objects.

Note that for the Junction, the class should be the class of the entity that defines the junction table.  The parentColumn should be the column that maps/references the @Embedded table. The entityColumn should be the column that maps/references the table with the  related children.



As a DEMO based upon your code (note Long rather than Int for the id's (as they should really be)) consider:-
The 3 tables i.e. @Entity annotated classes
@Entity
data class Train(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    val isFollow: Boolean
    )
@Entity
data class TrainStatus(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    val trainId: Long,
    val origin: String,
    val destination: String
    )
@Entity( indices = [
    Index("trainStatusId","previousTrainStatusId")
])
data class PreviousTrain(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    val trainStatusId: Long,
    val previousTrainStatusId: Long
    )

A POJO for a TrainStatus with it's related Train:-
data class TrainStatusWithTrain(
    @Embedded
    val trainStatus: TrainStatus,
    @Relation(
        entity = Train::class,
        parentColumn = "trainId",
        entityColumn = "id"
    )
    val train: Train
)

The POJO for a TrainStatus (with it's Train) and it's Previous TrainStatus (with it's Train):-
data class TrainStatusWithPreviousTrainStatus(
    @Embedded
    val trainStatusWithTrain: TrainStatusWithTrain,
    @Relation(
        entity = TrainStatus::class,
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "id",
        associateBy = Junction(
            PreviousTrain::class,
            parentColumn = "trainStatusId",
            entityColumn = "previousTrainStatusId"
        )
    )
    val previousTrainStatus: List<TrainStatusWithTrain>
)

Some Insert and a Query in an @Dao interface (so the use can be demonstrated):-
@Dao
interface AllDAOs{
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(train: Train): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(trainStatus: TrainStatus): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(previousTrain: PreviousTrain): Long

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM trainStatus")
    fun getAllTrainStatusesWithPreviousTrainStatuses(): List<TrainStatusWithPreviousTrainStatus>
}

A basic @Database annotated abstract class:-
@Database(entities = [Train::class,TrainStatus::class,PreviousTrain::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context, TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db"
                )
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}

Finally some activity code (not uses the main thread for brevity):-
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()

        /* Add Some Trains */
        val T1Id = dao.insert(Train(isFollow = true))
        val T2Id = dao.insert(Train(isFollow = false))
        val T3Id = dao.insert(Train(isFollow = true))
        /* and some TrainStatuses */
        val TS1Id = dao.insert(TrainStatus(trainId = T1Id, origin = "Place1", destination = "PlaceA"))
        val TS2Id = dao.insert(TrainStatus(trainId = T1Id, origin = "Place2", destination = "PlaceB"))
        val TS3Id = dao.insert(TrainStatus(trainId = T2Id, origin = "Place3", destination = "PlaceC"))
        val TS4Id = dao.insert(TrainStatus(trainId = TS3Id, origin = "Nowhere", destination = "Somewhere"))
        /* and some PreviousTrains */
        dao.insert(PreviousTrain(trainStatusId = TS1Id, previousTrainStatusId = TS2Id))
        dao.insert(PreviousTrain(trainStatusId = TS2Id, previousTrainStatusId = TS3Id))
        dao.insert(PreviousTrain(trainStatusId = TS3Id, previousTrainStatusId = TS1Id))

        /* Extract from the database, writing to the log */
        for (tswpts in dao.getAllTrainStatusesWithPreviousTrainStatuses()) {
            val sb = StringBuilder()
            for (pts in tswpts.previousTrainStatus) {
                sb.append("\n\tPREV TS ID is ${pts.trainStatus.id} " +
                        "TrainsID is ${pts.trainStatus.trainId} " +
                        " ISFollow is ${pts.train.isFollow} " +
                        "ORIGIN is ${pts.trainStatus.origin} " +
                        "DEST is ${pts.trainStatus.destination}")
            }
            Log.d("DBINFO","TS ID is ${tswpts.trainStatusWithTrain.trainStatus.id} " +
                    "TRAIN ID is ${tswpts.trainStatusWithTrain.train.id} ISFollow is ${tswpts.trainStatusWithTrain.train.isFollow} " +
                    "ORIGIN is ${tswpts.trainStatusWithTrain.trainStatus.origin} " +
                    "DEST is ${tswpts.trainStatusWithTrain.trainStatus.destination} " +
                    "TS has ${tswpts.previousTrainStatus.size} PREVIOUS TRAINS STATUSES. They are ${sb}")
        }
    }
}

Result (after first run, subsequent runs not intended for the demo):-
D/DBINFO: TS ID is 1 TRAIN ID is 1 ISFollow is true ORIGIN is Place1 DEST is PlaceA TS has 1 PREVIOUS TRAINS STATUSES. They are 
        PREV TS ID is 2 TrainsID is 1  ISFollow is true ORIGIN is Place2 DEST is PlaceB
D/DBINFO: TS ID is 2 TRAIN ID is 1 ISFollow is true ORIGIN is Place2 DEST is PlaceB TS has 1 PREVIOUS TRAINS STATUSES. They are 
        PREV TS ID is 3 TrainsID is 2  ISFollow is false ORIGIN is Place3 DEST is PlaceC
D/DBINFO: TS ID is 3 TRAIN ID is 2 ISFollow is false ORIGIN is Place3 DEST is PlaceC TS has 1 PREVIOUS TRAINS STATUSES. They are 
        PREV TS ID is 1 TrainsID is 1  ISFollow is true ORIGIN is Place1 DEST is PlaceA
D/DBINFO: TS ID is 4 TRAIN ID is 3 ISFollow is true ORIGIN is Nowhere DEST is Somewhere TS has 0 PREVIOUS TRAINS STATUSES. They are 


also note that a TrainStatus in the above has a single PreviousTrain but could have more (or none as is shown for TS 4). As such List<TrainStatus> could just be TrainStatus (with handling code modified to not expect a List) if there is only the one item.

The Required Response
If understood correctly (and for the demo assuming all trains) then
Adding the POJO:-
data class TrainWithTrainStatus(
    @Embedded
    val train: Train,
    @Relation(
        entity = TrainStatus::class,
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "trainId"
    )
    val trainStatusWithPreviousTrainStatus: List<TrainStatusWithPreviousTrainStatus>
)


noting that the use of the TrainStatusWithPreviousTrainStatus introduces the junction/junction table hierarchically.

And then introducing another function in the @Dao annotated interface:-
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM train")
fun  getAllTrainsWithTrainStatusetc(): List<TrainWithTrainStatus>

And then adding the activity code:-
    /* Train with TrainStatus etc */
    for (twtse in dao.getAllTrainsWithTrainStatusetc()) {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        for (twts in twtse.trainStatusWithPreviousTrainStatus) {
            val sb2 = StringBuilder()
            for (pt in twts.previousTrainStatus) {
                sb2.append("\n\t\t PTTS ID is ${pt.trainStatus.id} " +
                        "PTTS ORIGIN is ${pt.trainStatus.origin} " +
                        "PTTS DEST is ${pt.trainStatus.destination}")
            }
            sb.append("\n\t TS ID is ${twts.trainStatusWithTrain.trainStatus.id} " +
                    "ORIGIN is ${twts.trainStatusWithTrain.trainStatus.origin} " +
                    "DEST is ${twts.trainStatusWithTrain.trainStatus.destination} " +
                    ". There are ${twts.previousTrainStatus.size} PTTS's. They are ${sb2}")
        }
        Log.d("DBINFO","Train ID is ${twtse.train.id} ISFollow is ${twtse.train.isFollow} " +
                ". There are ${twtse.trainStatusWithPreviousTrainStatus.size} Trains Statuses With Previous Train Statuses. They are ${sb}")
    }

Results in (additionally):-
D/DBINFO: Train ID is 1 ISFollow is true . There are 2 Trains Statuses With Previous Train Statuses. They are 
         TS ID is 1 ORIGIN is Place1 DEST is PlaceA . There are 1 PTTS's. They are 
             PTTS ID is 2 PTTS ORIGIN is Place2 PTTS DEST is PlaceB
         TS ID is 2 ORIGIN is Place2 DEST is PlaceB . There are 1 PTTS's. They are 
             PTTS ID is 3 PTTS ORIGIN is Place3 PTTS DEST is PlaceC
D/DBINFO: Train ID is 2 ISFollow is false . There are 1 Trains Statuses With Previous Train Statuses. They are 
         TS ID is 3 ORIGIN is Place3 DEST is PlaceC . There are 1 PTTS's. They are 
             PTTS ID is 1 PTTS ORIGIN is Place1 PTTS DEST is PlaceA
D/DBINFO: Train ID is 3 ISFollow is true . There are 1 Trains Statuses With Previous Train Statuses. They are 
         TS ID is 4 ORIGIN is Nowhere DEST is Somewhere . There are 0 PTTS's. They are 

